# How to execute S4 class method in Python (using rpy2)?

Tags: python, r, rpy2, r-s4

I have made the following S4 class in R, its constructor takes a variable called 'A', which is a string. The class has a method called 'test_method', which takes as input a string 'B' and returns whether 'A' equals 'B'.

```
test_class <- setRefClass(
  "test_class",
  fields=list(A="character"),
  methods = list(
    test_method = function(B) {
       if (A==B) {
           return('yes')
       } else {
           return('no')
       }
    }
  )
)
```

Now, I can make an instance of this class and execute 'test_method' on it:

```
object <- test_class(A='hello')
object$test_method('hi')
```

This returns 'no', because the strings do not equal.

Now I want to save this object I have made and execute 'test_method' from Python. I make an RDS:

```
saveRDS(object, 'object.rds')
```

Now I know how to read this object into Python using rpy2 (however I don't really care which package to use, as it works):

```
from rpy2.robjects import R
r = R()
r_object = r.readRDS("object.rds")
```

But how can I execute 'test_method' now? I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
r_object.test_method('hi')
```

This throws: "AttributeError: 'RS4' object has no attribute 'test_method'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [rpy2 documentation about S4 classes](https://rpy2.github.io/doc/latest/html/robjects_oop.html#s4-objects) does not cover well reference classes mostly because the `rpy2` code predates the reference classes extension to S4.

In short, the S4 reference classes are not mapped to Python attributes, but writing a child Python class that does it is relatively easy.

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
test_class = ro.r("""
  setRefClass(
    "test_class",
    fields=list(A="character"),
    methods = list(
      test_method = function(B) {
         if (A==B) {
             return('yes')
         } else {
             return('no')
         }
      }
    )
  )
""")
s4obj = test_class(A='hello')
```

We have a rather generic S4 object:

```
>>> type(s4obj)
rpy2.robjects.methods.RS4
```

Writing a child class that inherits from that generic class can look like this:

```
class TestClass(ro.methods.RS4): 
    def test_method(self, b): 
        return ro.baseenv['$'](self, 'test_method')(b)
```

Casting is straightforward and computationally cheap (the parent class's constructor will just pass through an R object that is already an S4 object):

```
s4testobj = TestClass(s4obj)
```

Now we can do:

```
>>> tuple(s4testobj.test_method('hi'))  
 ('no',)
```

For additional automagical creation of methods and attributes in Python from the R class definition, and conversion to the custom child, you'll need to use metaprogramming on the Python side, and define custom conversion (there is a link to the latter in the link to the documentation provided earlier).

Note: If not tied to S4 Reference Classes, the R6 class system for R is worth a look. An `rpy2`'s mapping for that class system is here: https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2-R6.