# Trying to access R class methods and fields within Python using rpy2

Tags: r, python-3.x, class, rpy2, class-method

I am using rpy2 to import a library from CRAN repository called "MatrixEQTL" to run in within Python using importr, here is my attempt:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr

robjects.r('install.packages("MatrixEQTL")')
mtrql = importr('MatrixEQTL')
```

I am trying to access both class fields as well as class methods but I failed here is what the class looks like when printing into the python shell:

```
# to view class SlicedData of MatrixEQTL R package
print(mtrql.SlicedData)

Generator for class "SlicedData":

Class fields:
                                                           
Name:             dataEnv           nSlices1      rowNameSlices
Class:        environment            numeric               list
                                                           
Name:         columnNames      fileDelimiter    fileSkipColumns 
Class:          character          character            numeric
                                                           
Name:        fileSkipRows      fileSliceSize fileOmitCharacters
Class:            numeric            numeric          character

Class Methods: 
 "Clear", "show#envRefClass", "nSlices", "getRefClass", "export", 
 "initialize", "CombineInOneSlice", "callSuper", "initFields", "nCols", 
 "getClass", "RowStandardizeCentered", "import", "SaveFile", "RowReorder", 
 "setSlice", "getSlice", "RowReorderSimple", "CreateFromMatrix", "nRows", 
 "ResliceCombined", "LoadFile", "ColumnSubsample", "SetNanRowMean", 
 "setSliceRaw", "getSliceRaw", "copy", "RowMatrixMultiply", "usingMethods", 
 "GetAllRowNames", "RowRemoveZeroEps", "field", ".objectParent", 
 "IsCombined", "untrace", "trace", "Clone", "GetNRowsInSlice", 
 ".objectPackage", "show", "FindRow"

 Reference Superclasses: 
 "envRefClass"
```

I want to access for instance class field say `fileDelimiter` and also class Methods say `LoadFile`  but I couldn't, here is also my attempt to access class method LoadFile and the error message that generated:

```
# If I try to run this without "()"
data = mtrql.SlicedData

load_my_file = data.LoadFile(file)

    data = data.LoadFile(file)
 AttributeError: 'DocumentedSTFunction' object has no attribute 'LoadFile'

 # And that's my attempt for when adding "()" to the class name

 data = mtrql.SlicedData

 load_my_file = data.LoadFile(file)
    data = data.LoadFile(file)
 AttributeError: 'RS4' object has no attribute 'LoadFile'
```

I tried to look for a solution to this issue but I wasn't successful, please help me understand and solve this issue.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Hi, @Parfait I corrected my code for mtrql sorry about that I had another different name for variable called MQL, never mind that. Anyways, that is the minimal reproducible example I have. I rerun the snipped codes and did produce the issue. Thanks

Comment: According to [docs](http://www.bios.unc.edu/research/genomic_software/Matrix_eQTL/html/SlicedData-class.html), you have to initialize with `new()` method. Try `data = mtrql.SlicedData.new()`. Otherwise, show the correct working R code.

Comment: I got the following error: data = MQL.SlicedData.new()
AttributeError: 'DocumentedSTFunction' object has no attribute 'new'

Comment: Then try: `data = mtrql.SlicedData().new()`

Comment: AttributeError: 'RS4' object has no attribute 'new'

Comment: Leave out `.new()`

Answer (score 0):

`mtrql.SlicedData` is a "Generator", that is a constructor. In R that means a function (that will return an instance of the class), which is why `mtrql.SlicedData` is an R function with rpy2.

Consider the following example from the R documentation (https://rdrr.io/r/methods/Introduction.html):

```
import rpy2.robjects as ro
Pos = ro.r("""
setClass("Pos", slots = c(latitude = "numeric", longitude = "numeric",
                          altitude = "numeric"))
""")
```

With `rpy2`, the object `Pos` is an R function:

```
>>> type(Pos)
rpy2.robjects.functions.SignatureTranslatedFunction
```

However that function object has an S3 class in R (there are several OOP systems in R, 2 of them coexisting in standard R unfortunately).

```
>>> tuple(Pos.rclass)
('classGeneratorFunction',)
```

A specific `print` function is implemented for this S3 class, and it will use the attributes `package` and `className` for the object (the R function-that-is-in-fact-a-Generator) to display all the info about the clas you are seeing.

Since this is a constructor, to create an instance you can do:

```
pos = Pos()
```

or

```
pos = Pos(latitude=0, longitude=0, altitude=-10)
```

The instance will have instance attributes (and methods)

```
>>> tuple(pos.list_attrs())
('latitude', 'longitude', 'altitude', 'class')
>>> tuple(pos.do_slot('altitude'))
(-10,)
```

With your specific example, you probably want something like:

```
slidata = mtrql.SlicedData()
slidata.do_slot('LoadFile')(file)
```

The documentation can provide more information about R S4 classes in `rpy2`, and how to make wrapper classes in Python that map attributes and methods.

https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v3.3.x/html/robjects_oop.html#s4-objects

Comment: Thank you for your answer when I try testing those above lines, I get the following error
    raise LookupError(name)
LookupError: LoadFile

Comment: I have not looked at what kind of class `SlicedData` is. Some R S4 classes (e.g.,  RefClass) implement attribute and methods differently. Try with `$` instead of `do_slot` (see my answer for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63069677/how-to-execute-s4-class-method-in-python-using-rpy2/63083717#63083717)